# Drools decision tables performance

Tags: performance, drools

I'm using Drools decision tables. I have an .XSL file with condition columns, an action column, and several rows. Everything is working fine, but I'm worried about performance if the decision table start growing.
Does anybody know if there is some kind of limitations in decision tables? or something to keep in mind about the number of rows/columns that could affect the performance?
The application needs to be always available, and decision tables are taking care of a critical part of my application, and thats why I'm worried.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Decision tables are converted to regular drools rules, each row in your excel table will be a drools rule. It will not affect the performace of your system whether your rules are in technical DRL rules or decision tables.

Since Drools uses RETE algorithm, number of rules does not affect performance as it would be in sequential engines. Keeping number of objects in your working memory small and not using eval is much more important, performance wise.